# How to call the same function multiple times by using different ids

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to call same function in multiple times using dropdown values. It works for the first one only, the remaining two do not work. How can I solve this?

```html
<button id="jointables" onclick="joinsTable()" class="btn btn-success report-btn" data-toggle="collapse">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Join Tables
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" class="table">One Table Join</a>
    <a href="#" class="table">Two Table Join</a>
    <a href="#" class="table">Three Table Join</a>
  </div>
</button>
```

```js
$('.table').click(function(e) {
  $(".collapse").toggle();
```

Comment: you can define onclick method like this for all anchor tag  e.g
<a href="#" onclick="your_function()" class="table">One Table Join </a>
<a href="#" onclick="your_function()" class="table">Two Table Join </a>

Comment: You're mixing `onclick=` with `$().click` - they're probably conflicting with each other (as you've not included the `joinsTable()` function.   Try creating a working snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: no why we add onclick in here no use

Comment: joinstable() is for dropdown only

Comment: the dropdown you created are inside the parent  button so after first click it will trigger the parent click event i.e. joinTables() which is not defined so throws error joinsTable is not defined. This is the main issue. Provide the joinTable() function code also

Comment: function joinsTable() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.report-btn')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: @Nandinip please check below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button id="jointables" onclick="joinsTable()" class="btn btn-success report-btn" data-toggle="collapse">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i>
  </button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" class="table">One Table Join</a>
    <a href="#" class="table">Two Table Join</a>
    <a href="#" class="table">Three Table Join</a>
  </div>
 </div>

$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-content a', function () {
    alert($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: @Nandinip i update my answer , please check whatever the anchor tag is click that anchor tag text will display, it means every anchor tag clicked and you can call here your desire method.

Comment: @Nandinip you are not getting output , because of your html  you are wrapping dropdown div inside button.

Comment: @Nandinip please check answer now. it will work like a charm.

Comment: but i have another query also please help me

Comment: when we click two table join dropdown it displays function two times how is it help me

Comment: @Nandinip if solution works ,please accept my answer :)

Comment: @Nandinip it's depend on joinsTable() function , what are you doing inside this , handle duplicate value inside this function.

Comment: joinstable function is for dropdown purpose i thought taht in js we can candle it ,but i have no idea how to do will you help me

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap, upgrade to 4. No extra jQuery is required only the correct attributes in HTML.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='dropdown'>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <i class="fas fa-random"></i>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Join Tables</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item table">One Table Join</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item table">Two Table Join</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item table">Three Table Join</a>
  </div>
</div>
  
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```